# Proper way to compare rand variables inside of a class?

Tags: ruby

In this example:

```
class random
  randNum = rand(1)
  randNum2 = rand(1)
end

if randNum == randNum2
  puts("the numbers you rolled matched")
else
  puts("the numbers you rolled did not match")
end
```

The error I receive is:

`<main>': undefined local variable or method`randNum' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  rand

What is this proper way to compare these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `randNum` within a class. You then try and call it outside the class.

If this is just a script, you should use:

```
randNum = rand(6)
randNum2 = rand(6)


if randNum == randNum2
  puts("the numbers you rolled matched")
else
  puts("the numbers you rolled did not match")
end
```

However if you're wanting to use a class, something along the following would work:

```
class Random
  attr_accessor :rand_1, :rand_2     

  def initialize
    self.rand_1 = rand(6)
    self.rand_2 = rand(6)
  end

  def match?
    rand_1 == rand_2
  end

  def does_match?
    if match?
      puts("the numbers you rolled matched")
    else
      puts("the numbers you rolled did not match")
    end
  end

end

generator = Random.new
generator.does_match?
```

Also note that `rand(1)` will always return 0, so you probably want to just use `rand` or define a different parameter eg. `6`